# Vs code terminal issue

Tags: java, powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal

When I tried to run java code in visual studio code, the terminal is throwing an error

> PowerShell terminated with exit code:4294901760

I have searched all queries but nothing is relatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install java in VS-Code. To do so you can just search "java" in the extensions search bar. after that you will see an extension called "Java Extension Pack", install it and then you issue will hopefully be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I tried this, actual issue was windows power shell, unchecked run engine of powershell from  windows features -->programs-->control panel. Then restarted the pc after then my powershell opened and same worked.